# State of Ajax request on response.getWriter().write()

Tags: javascript, java, ajax, spring-mvc, servlets

I have a spring MVC webapp, where I have a following controller

```
@ResourceMapping("getPermission")
    @ResponseBody
    public ModelAndView getPermission(ResourceRequest request,
            ResourceResponse response){
.
.Do something..
.
                Iterator<String> iterator = permissionList.iterator();             
                     while(iterator.hasNext()){
                        String perm = iterator.next();
                        if(perm.equalsIgnoreCase("Create")){
                            response.getWriter().write("true");
                        }
                    }
                return null;
}
```

And my Ajax request is

```
$.ajax({
   url:availableUrls.permUrl,
   success:function(result){
    if(result=='true'){
       Do something..    

    }
  }
});
```

Now when we do `response.getWriter().write("true");` will the ajax request be closed? or if `permissionList` has got more than 2 values as `Create`, then will it write `true` twice?

Will the request be closed once we write something to the response or not it is the confusion. Your support is appreciated.

Comment: Why dont you try it?

Comment: Ok I tried it , and thats what it is.. it will loop through and write to response multiple times.. thanks for the suggestion though :)